# How do I show the delete and edit links only to the user who has posted the comment?

Tags: php

How can I show the delete and edit link to the user who has posted the comment? Just like in Facebook only the person who has posted the comment is allowed to edit or delete the comment. Below are my "show comments", "show delete" and "edit comment" PHP files:

```
<?php
    include_once("includes/settings.php");
    connect();
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC");
    echo "<table width='80%' border=0>";
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>";
    echo "<td>Name</td>";
    echo "<td>Comments</td>";;
    echo "</tr>";

    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$res['Name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['Comments']."</td>"; 
        echo "<td><a href=\"edit_comment.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"includes/delete.php?id=$res[id]\">Delete</a></td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Below is edit.php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    include_once("settings.php");
    connect();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $Comments=$_POST['Comments'];
        if(empty($Comments)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Comments field is empty.</font><br/>";
        }
        else {  
            $result=mysql_query("UPDATE comments SET Comments='$Comments' WHERE id=$id");
            echo "Your comments has been edited you will be redirected to the members area page automatically or <a href='../index_ma.php'>click here to go back</a>";
            header('refresh: 3; url=../index_ma.php');
        }
    }
?>
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result=mysql_query("select * from comments where id='$id'");
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $Comments = $res['Comments'];
    }
?>
```

Below is delete.php

```
<?php
    include_once("settings.php");
    connect();
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM comments where id=$id");
    echo "Your comments has been deleted you will be redirected to the members area page automatically or <a href='../index_ma.php'>click here to go back</a>";
    header('refresh: 3; url=../index_ma.php');
?>
```

Comment: have you tried...if so what's the problem????

Comment: and the question is .......

Comment: Hi what i need is the links to display only to the user who has posted the comment only e.g the comment was posted by pinkpanther then the edit and delete link should only show to you. the problem is that the links are displayed on every comment that has been made

Comment: i dont know how to go about it thats y am asking here...the above code is what i have done so far the links are the only issues

Comment: Don’t forget not only showing the links to the right user only, but also making sure (POST) requests that want to actually alter data are checked for whether or not the user has the right to perform that action as well.

Comment: @CBroe thnx yes i know but i dont have a clue on how to go on please help me with the codes i provided i am stuck and have to hand in the project tommorow

Comment: Sorry, but no one here is gonna write code for you just because you went in over your head with a project. You have gotten multiple suggestions and hints already, so show us what you are able to make of them.

Comment: @CBroe yes i know but i have no idea what and how to go on i dont want some one to write the code for me

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your database schema. I am assuming you have a column that stores the user id. With that, you would so something like this:

```
if ($CurrentUserId == $res['CommentatorId']) {
  echo "<td><a href=\"edit_comment.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"includes/delete.php?id=$res[id]\">Delete</a></td>";
}
else {
  echo "<td></td>";
}
```

You would use the above block instead of your `echo "<td><a href=...` line in the first code block.

This is how your block would look:

```
<?php
    include_once("includes/settings.php");
    connect();
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC");
    echo "<table width='80%' border=0>";
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>";
    echo "<td>Name</td>";
    echo "<td>Comments</td>";;
    echo "</tr>";

    while($res=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$res['Name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['Comments']."</td>"; 
        if ($CurrentUserId == $res['CommentatorId']) {
            echo "<td><a href=\"edit_comment.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"includes/delete.php?id=$res[id]\">Delete</a></td>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<td></td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: hi i tried the above code but it doesnt display the links now

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you do so 
but in your comments table you need to save the id of the user who posted the comment, then in edit.php you need to check if the id of the user logged in is equal to the id of the person trying to edit the comment
If yes, then edit, if not then don't allow him to edit it.

In the following code I will suppose that you save the id of the user in the comments table as user_id

```
$comment_id = intval($_GET['id']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM Comments WHERE id = $comment_id");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row['user_id'] == $user_id) {
  // Edit the comment
} else {
  // Not permitted to edit the comment
}
```

I also noticed that you are still using mysql which got deprecated so I suggest you start using mysqli, I also noticed that you are not sanitizing your variables which is very wrong and could cause your database to be injected. Also, in edit.php you sent the id in a link so that is $_GET not $_POST as I edited in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is applicable only if there is users and login system on your application. If we suppose that the field Name in your comments table is unique and assign the user name (from users table of course) that had wrote the comment, so during a successful login, you have to set this Name value in a session variable, then during printing out the comments you check for this session value and the Name value of the comment to print out the edit and delete links.

**Notice:** This answer is an [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) of implementation.

Comment: hello thanks for the reply yes there is a login system where the session stores the username and the comments table has a unique field called id and so does the registration table it also has a unique field which is id aswell